# how to add a script to script js

Tags: javascript, html, widget, hide

how to add a:

```js
Tawk_API.hideWidget();

//Example

Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    Tawk_API.hideWidget();
};

Tawk_API.toggleVisibility();


//Example

Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    Tawk_API.toggleVisibility();
};
```

to

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {

 window.print();
});
    </script>
```

I need hide a chat widget on print page. When i print a page i have a small widget with chat in right bottom corner.

Comment: why not you write it directly to script tag?

Comment: I dont know how, could you write it for me?

Comment: write it before </script> end as simple.

Comment: ok but it hide a widget also on page, but i need hide it only on print page :(

Comment: Please check I posted the answer for you,  accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if hiding a widget on the print page means when you click on the print button is only your concern then it will work for you because as I can see in your code you add an event listener to a #print. so I am assuming that works as a print button for you. 
you can uncomment the code if you required that I marked as a comment.
write the following code as you required. Please vote up and accept the answer if it helps you.

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
  
document.querySelector("#print").addEventListener("click", function() {
     Tawk_API.hideWidget();
    
//i dont know why you write below code so i mark it as comment you can uncomment if you need it.
//Example
/*
Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    Tawk_API.hideWidget();
};

Tawk_API.toggleVisibility();


//Example

Tawk_API.onLoad = function(){
    Tawk_API.toggleVisibility();
};*/
 window.print();
});
    </script>
```